# How to create bubble plot with timeline by echarts4r?

Tags: r, bubble-chart, echarts4r

I tried to create a bubble plot with timeline as below:

```
library(echarts4r)
library(tidyverse)

df<-data.frame(siteid=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3)),
           year=rep(c(2001,2005,2010),3),
           population=c(c(10,30,40),c(15,35,50),c(12,40,60)),
           dis=c(c(2,5,10),c(2,0,0),c(0,5,10)))

df |> 
  group_by(year)|> 
  e_charts(population,timeline = TRUE) |>
  e_scatter(dis,population)
```

However, there was nothing showed up.

In general, I'd like to know how to plot it in the right way. I'd like the bubble size determined by the different values of population and color determined by siteid while making the x and y axis to be stabilized, so that I could see the bubbles growing and moving through the timeline.

Comment: Size is the population. Clarify: What do you want to show on x-axis and on y-axis?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'd like to set the population as the x axis, and dis as the y axis

Comment: @Robin you cross posted this question, I gave you an answer ok GitHub https://github.com/JohnCoene/echarts4r/issues/525